# Transcoding old mjpeg avi's to h264

Tags: sound, xubuntu, video, avconv

I have a collection of private jpeg’s and avi’s (mjpeg format) recorded with Olympus u5000 camera.
As mjpeg is not a suitable format for playing in xbmc, I would like to transcode it to h264 format.
The furthest I have got is the following line:

```
avconv -i P3040001.AVI -strict experimental -c:v libx264 -b:v 8000k -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k output.mp4
```

This line converts:

```
avconv version 9.11-6:9.11-2ubuntu2, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 24 2014 06:12:33 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-17ubuntu1)
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
Input #0, avi, from 'P3040001.AVI':
  Metadata:
    creation_time   : 2013-03-04 12:21:39
    encoder         : OLYMPUS u5000
  Duration: 00:00:01.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12920 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p, 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_u8, 8000 Hz, mono, u8, 64 kb/s
```

to

```
avconv version 9.11-6:9.11-2ubuntu2, Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the Libav developers
  built on Mar 24 2014 06:12:33 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-17ubuntu1)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'output.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 2013-03-04 12:21:39
    encoder         : Lavf54.20.3
  Duration: 00:00:02.09, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 35 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 640x480, 17 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn, 60 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-04 12:21:39
    Stream #0.1(und): Audio: aac, 8000 Hz, mono, fltp, 9 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2013-03-04 12:21:39
```

As you can see, I have a problem with audio. In output.mp4 there is no audio at all.
I would like to use avconv because I have bunch of files on my xubuntu 14.04 server.

What I am doing wrong?

Regards.

Comment: What does this do `avconv -i P3040001.AVI -strict experimental -c:a libx264 -b:v 8000k -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k output.mp4` ?

Comment: Cornelius, I have tried your suggestion but now I have the audio but quality of the video is very bad. Output of the avconv is bellow:

Comment: Here is the output. I had a problem to pastebin it.

http://pastebin.com/TvBQ5YvS

Comment: Note that in my first comment I made a mistake. This should be the command `avconv -i P3040001.AVI -strict experimental -c:v libx264 -b:v 8000k -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k output.mp4`. `-c:v` instead of `-c:a`

Comment: The quality of the video is very bad due to reducing the bitrate from 12920 kb/s (source rate from your pastebin) to 8000k (target rate from your question)

Comment: Looks like now everything is OK. This is the output of the avconv command: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7388440/

As I can see avi file 3.155 KB is converted to mp4 1.908 KB, which means the file will be also lighter. 

I will try to do the conversion on some bigger file and then I will report back.

For now, one big thanks. I have spent few hours in order to figure out what to do with switches but with no success.

Comment: @Cornelius I have converted a big file to the h264 and everything went OK. In this file http://paste.ubuntu.com/7391214/
you can see the output of the avconv and video information of both files. The only thing that bothers me is am I preserving the quality?
If you look at file formats, original file has higher bitrate (13842 kb/s compared to 8110 kb/s).
Furthermore, original audio is in 64 kb/s and output is in 160 kb/s, which means that the output file is slightly bigger than it should be.

Everything else looks OK to me.

Comment: @Elder Geek

My idea is to convert the file to the more suitable format with no quality change.

Comment: @user3225309 well you wanted 8000 kb/s bitrate. Change `-b:v 14000k`

Comment: @user3225309 -b:v chooses the video bitrate. Cornelius is correct that in increasing the bitrate to one higher than your source you should have no loss of quality in the video.  You can obtain the bitrate of your existing video by using the command avconv -i VIDEOFILENAME. This info is in your OP in this block     creation_time   : 2013-03-04 12:21:39
    encoder         : OLYMPUS u5000
  Duration: 00:00:01.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 12920 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p, 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_u8, 8000 Hz, mono, u8, 64 kb/s

Comment: @user3225309 I edited your question and corrected it with this info from your comment. avconv -i P3040001.AVI -strict experimental -c:v libx264 -b:v 8000k -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k output.mp4

Comment: @Elder Geek
If you look at the following lines:
Duration: 00:14:29.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 13842 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p, 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn
    Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_u8, 8000 Hz, mono, u8, 64 kb/s

You can see that overall bitrate is 13842 kb/s, and than I have 64 kb/s for audio. In your line video should be recoded with 8000k?!? and audio at 192k.
This is different than original file isn't it?

Comment: @user3225309 Nowhere in your question do I see the lines you mention in the above comment. "If you look at the following lines: Duration: 00:14:29.99, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 13842 kb/s Stream #0.0: Video: mjpeg, yuvj422p, 640x480, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 30 tbn Stream #0.1: Audio: pcm_u8, 8000 Hz, mono, u8, 64 kb/s" See the answer below it has been modified.

Comment: @user3225309 I thought I copied that edit directly from your comment. If it's not accurate please edit your question.

Comment: @Elder Geek
I have made a research. Looks like my avi files have variable bitrate, from 2498 - 13865 kb/s in Duration line. On the other hand sound is always pcm_u8, 8000 Hz, mono, u8, 64 kb/s.
I would like to make a script that will convert all videos from mjpeg to h264. What to do with variable rate?
Should I use a constant let's say at 14000 or...?
As you can see I have never done something like this before. :)

Comment: @user3225309 the bitrate specified is usually a guideline and the encoder will attempt to average near that rate AFAIK. storage is so cheap nowadays I never concern myself much with the size of the output anymore. The rate you should use varies with the quality of the input, and the larger the rate the larger the ending file.  I find in most cases between b:v 500k and c:v 800k is sufficient for my quality needs. Try a couple and adjust to your liking

Answer (score 1):

In your command you were not specifying what should be done with the audio track.

Try this:

```
avconv -i P3040001.AVI -strict experimental -c:v libx264 -b:v 8000k -c:a ac3 -b:a 192k output.mp4.
```

Feel free to tweak the bitrates as you like. You may use `avinfo` to get an idea about original bitrate and transcode to a similar one.

You can also use a GUI program like Avidemux.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I believe that task like this one could be accomplished by avconv.
I would like to avoid introducing new programs for simple task, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @Cornelius It looks like you got user3225309 on the right track. Why not edit your answer with the info from your comments so I can upvote it?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 avconv -i input.avi -c:v libx264 -b 800k output.mp4
```

this will reencode the video using the libx264 codec with the rate at 800k and let the encoder decide to what to do with the audio to insure compatibility with the mp4 container. Adjust bit rates to your quality preference. All things considered you should allow higher bitrates for larger movies. (for instance a movie that is 1280x960 would need roughly 4 times the bitrate of one 640x480 to maintain a similar quality)

Comment: This what I got:

http://pastebin.com/b4EAM3pP

Comment: @user3225309 I edited the answer after further research and to take into account your new information.  I removed -strict experimental as I don't think it's necessary. I also realized that

Comment: @user3225309 reviewing your pastebin above

Comment: @user3225309 It looks like Cornelius got you where you need to be, yes? Don't expect your re-encoded files to be the same size as the originals due to the different methods employed. Also AFAIK there is a minimum audio bitrate that must be used in order for you to get the results you want with avconv.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps best option would be to use a *preset* for the x264 encoding and specify Constant Rate Factor (CRF) rather than a fixed bitrate. Sound from the source is not the best to start with but perhaps a conversion to a relatively low bitrate VBR mp3 might sound ok. Try the following:

```
avconv -i P3040001.AVI \
   -c:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 22 -tune film \
   -c:a libmp3lame -qscale:a 7 -ar 44100 \
   output.mp4
```

and this might give reasonable video quality and perhaps better sound. Adjust the *-qscale:a 7* setting for better sound, a lower number will give a higher bitrate target.

If avconv chokes on either x264 or libmp3lame you will need to  add in the appropriate *libavcodec-extra**  package appropriate for your version of Ubuntu.